# How do I split a list of phrases into words so I can use counter on them?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, counter

My data are conversation threads from a webforum.  I created a function to clean the data of stop words, punctuation, and such.  Then I created a loop to clean all the posts which were in my csv file and put them into a list.  Then I did the word count.  My problem is that list contains unicode phrases rather than individual words.  How can I split up the phrases, so they are individual words that I can count.  Here is my code below:

```
 def post_to_words(raw_post):
      HTML_text = BeautifulSoup(raw_post).get_text()
      letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", HTML_text)
      words = letters_only.lower().split()
      stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))   
      meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
      return( " ".join(meaningful_words))

clean_Post_Text = post_to_words(fiance_forum["Post_Text"][0])
clean_Post_Text_split = clean_Post_Text.lower().split()
num_Post_Text = fiance_forum["Post_Text"].size
clean_posts_list = [] 

for i in range(0, num_Post_Text):
    clean_posts_list.append( post_to_words( fiance_forum["Post_Text"][i]))

from collections import Counter
     counts = Counter(clean_posts_list)
     print(counts)
```

My output looks like this: u'please follow instructions notice move receiver':1
I want it to look like this:

please: 1

follow: 1

instructions: 1

and so on....thanks so much!

Comment: @Coder256, Gina's code is showing one instance of the unicode string instead of counting one instance of each word in the string.

Comment: Why are you using `str.join` if you want an individual list of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a list of words so you don't need to split anything, forget calling *str.join* i.e `" ".join(meaningful_words)` and just create a *Counter* dict and update on each call to `post_to_words`, you are also doing way to much work, all you need to do is iterate over `fiance_forum["Post_Text"]` passing each element to the function. You only also need to create the set of stopwords once, not on every iteration:

```
from collections import Counter

def post_to_words(raw_pos, st):
    HTML_text = BeautifulSoup(raw_post).get_text()
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", HTML_text)
    words = letters_only.lower().split()
    return (w for w in words if w not in st)



cn = Counter()
st = set(stopwords.words("english"))
for post in fiance_forum["Post_Text"]:
    cn.update(post_to_words(post, st)
```

That also avoids the need to create a huge list of words by doing the counting as you go.

Comment: okay I tried this, but now I would like the output.  What would I key in at this point?  Sorry...I'm new.

Comment: @GinaBoBina, the counts are stored in cn

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there, all you need is to split the string into words:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('please follow instructions notice move receiver'.split())
Counter({'follow': 1,
         'instructions': 1,
         'move': 1,
         'notice': 1,
         'please': 1,
         'receiver': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you.  I probably should mention that there are over 400000+ posts, so since I cannot type out the entire post for each is there another way to get it column individual words like this?   Sorry if the answer is obvious...I am new.  Thanks again!

Comment: @GinaBoBina I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @aldanor...oh, sorry.  I just meant that Count('please follow instructions notice move receiver'.split()) will split this sentence up, which is great.  However, I have more than 400000 sentences to split up.  Does this make more sense?  Thanks again!

Comment: @GinaBoBina I just measured the time, on my box splitting the sentence from the example takes 400 nanoseconds, while splitting and counting takes about 5 microseconds. Either way, it would probably take just a few seconds to churn through 400k posts. Also, as was already mentioned above, if you already have a list of "meaningful words", you don't need to join them into a string only to then split again, you can pass that directly to  the Counter.