# How do I write words and their frequencies into two separate columns in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have the desired input (a `Counter` object, from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423684/how-do-i-split-a-list-of-phrases-into-words-so-i-can-use-counter-on-them)), which looks like this:

```
 (u'twice', 4302),

 (u'thru', 4286),

 (u'mailing', 4276),

 (u'specifically', 4274),
```

etc.

Now, I am trying to write the words and their frequency values into a CSV file.  I tried the following code below, which I got from a similar question on this site:

```
with open("fiancee_wordfreq.csv" , "wb") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)  
     for val in cn:
         writer.writerow([val])
```

When I open the CSV file in Excel, I find that only the words but not their frequencies.  So, "specifically" is one of the words listed in column A, but not 4274.  I would like to have the word in column A and the frequency in column B, but I can't get the frequency to show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through a `Counter` is like iterating through a dictionary - you only get the keys. `writerow()` requires a sequence, so `val` isn't enough, but wrapping it in brackets to make a `list` with `[val]` just allows you to write that key as a single column. Use the `items()` method to get a key as well as its associated value:

```
with open("fiancee_wordfreq.csv" , "wb") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)  
     for pair in cn.items():
         writer.writerow(pair)
```

Or use each key to index the `Counter`:

```
with open("fiancee_wordfreq.csv" , "wb") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)  
     for val in cn:
         writer.writerow([val, cn[val]])
```